# get a String from a match on ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

```
"A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"
```

A regular expression:

```
/[^[^\w*]]/
```

The required result is:

```
"AmanaplanacanalPanama"
```

The problem: I cant get a string of that result. This is my code:

```
def palindromo(s)  #s is a string

  num_expr = /[^[^\w*]]/
  m = s.match(num_expr)
  unless m
    puts "no hubo concordancia"
    exit
  end
  print "El string de la busqueda es: " 
  puts m.string   # string donde se efectúa la búsqueda 
  print "La parte del string que concuerda con la busqueda es: " 

  puts m
```

The code gives me this result: `"A"`, and i want get this string:
`"AmanaplanacanalPanama"`

Comment: You need to clean up the formatting of that code first, as you've missed out an `end` at the very least.

Comment: I've cleaned it up as best I can, and while I did I noticed that your code has tab characters in it. If you're going to get along with other programmers then I suggest you set your tab key to output spaces!

Answer (score 2):

```
"A man, a plan, a canal -- Panama".gsub( /[^\w]/, "" ) == "AmanaplanacanalPanama"
# => true
```

Comment: `[^\w]` can be shortened to `\W`

Comment: @pguardiario very true, good catch :) http://zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#regexen is a helpful list.

Answer (score 1):

```
puts "El string de la busqueda es: #{s}"
puts s[/\W/] ? "La parte del string que concuerda con la busqueda es: #{s.gsub( /[^\w]/, "" ) }" : "no hubo concordancia"
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do `s[/\W/]`, very interesting. +1